# Mysql: Get records from last date

Tags: mysql

I want to get all records which are not "older" than 20 days. If there are no records within 20 days, I want all records from the most recent day. I'm doing this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) FROM t
WHERE 
(DATEDIFF(NOW(), t.created) <= 20 
OR 
(date(t.created) >= (SELECT max(date(created)) FROM t)));
```

This works so far, but it is awful slow. created is a datetime, might be due tue the conversion to a date... Any ideas how to speed this up?

Comment: You should, in your table, format the dates in Unix Timestamp (numbers of seconds from 1970), in this way the comparison should get faster.

Comment: Use the EXPLAIN statement right before your SELECT to get all information where MySQL looses time.

Comment: Might be you are just missing an index on created.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
 SELECT * FROM t WHERE datediff(now(),created) between 0 and 20
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t WHERE created<now() LIMIT 1) last1
) last20d
```

I used the `between` clause just in case there might be dates in the future in the table. These will be excluded. Also you can simplify the select, if you *just*  need the `count()` to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
 SELECT id FROM t WHERE datediff(now(),created) between 0 and 20
 UNION 
 SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM t WHERE created<now() LIMIT 1) last1
) last20d
```

otherwise, in the first select version you can leave out the outer select if you want all the data of the chosen records. The `UNION` will make sure that duplicates will be excluded (in other cases I always use `UNION ALL` since it is faster).